# Comparing Floating Numbers Error

Tags: java

I created a text file with 15 random floating numbers and I'm trying to create a program which compares them all starting from the first until the last one.
I used the

`if (stocksList.get(i) > stocksList.get(i+1))`

for comparing and `scanner.nextDouble` to read them. 
My problem is when it's on the last two numbers it compares them but It gives an error because there's no 16th number due to using `i+1`. 
Is there another way to fix or should i try it with `nextLine` and convert them from string to double?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
throws IOException
{
int num, countUp, countDown, countSame;
num = 0;
countUp = 0;
countDown = 0;
countSame = 0;
FileInputStream stocks = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stocks);
ArrayList<Double> stocksList = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
  stocksList.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
//Dilbert's Rule
for(int i=0;i<stocksList.size(); i++)
{
  num++;
  System.out.printf(num + "%8.3f",stocksList.get(i));
  if(stocksList.get(i+1) > stocksList.get(i))
  {
  countUp++;
  }
  else if (stocksList.get(i+1) < stocksList.get(i))
  {
    countDown++;
  }
  else
  {
    countSame++;
  }
  if(countUp >= 3 && (countDown > 1 || countSame >= 1))
  {
    System.out.print(" " + "SELL");
    countUp = 0;
    countSame = 0;
  }
  else if (countDown >= 3 && (countUp > 1 || countSame >= 1))
  {
    System.out.print(" " + "BUY");
    countDown = 0;
    countSame = 0;
  }
System.out.println();
}
}
```

I made some MAJOR modifications since last time and now the on problem i get is the IndexOutOfBoundsException. If i but the -1 on the for loop as many suggested it goes away but i lose my 15th line.

Comment: restrict the loop to run while `i < stocksList.size()-1`

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @alfasin `i < stocksList.size()-1`, right? That is *first* to [*penultimate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch right - my bad :) fixing...

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but please also see [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)

Comment: @MiserableVariable will check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically mistake called +-1. 
You should use one of the options:

- Rewrite your loop and set max value to length - 1,
- Add if statement and skip checking if I or I + 1 getting out of the array

Also in your print statement you write if current value rise or fall. But you can't know the future and can't compare value15 with value16. This is again the same mistake. 
If you have n measures, you have only n - 1 rises or falls. That's because you should make another loop to print all values, or add if statement to ensure you are not getting out of array, and make one loop to go through all indexes.

**option 1:**

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
  stocksList.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
stocks.close();

for(int i=0;i<stocksList.size(); i++)
{
  System.out.printf(num + "%8.3f",stocksList.get(i));
}

for(int i=0;i<stocksList.size() - 1 ;i++)
{
  ... skiped code ...
}
```

**option 2:**

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
  stocksList.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
stocks.close();

for(int i=0;i<stocksList.size();i++)
{
  if (i + 1 < stocksList.size())  
  { // in other case we cant say is it count up or count down
    if (stocksList.get(i) > stocksList.get(i+1))
    {
        countUp ++;
    }
    else
    {
        countDown ++;
    }
  }

  ... skiped code ...

  System.out.printf(num + "%8.3f",stocksList.get(i));
  System.out.println(" " + choice+ " " + countUp + " " +countDown); 
}
```

Comment: i did it with size - 1 and got 14 results again since it removed 1 of my doubles and got rid of the error

Comment: @KyprosVassiliou, I have updated my answer according to question code sample

Comment: so either way i'll have the same prob. If i rewrite the whole program with 'nextLine' and make it to read the line and convert them from string to double, do you think it might work or still the same problem? was thinking to do it like this and add an empty line but then it should give me an error

Comment: I was resetting the counters to see the flow because my compiler doesn't have a debugger on it

Comment: In my opinion better would be skip all empty lines and not values in scanner. Do I answer to all yours questions?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions: if you're using a "for" to check every line, you should write it like this `for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)`
The second solution involves using a while like this `while (scanner.hasNextLine())`